# Mapping a foreign key ID in DTO to an Object using AutoMapper and AutoFac IOC

Tags: asp.net-web-api, automapper, autofac

Im my Web API project, am trying to map the id in DTO call to the Object. But I am facing issues in setting up  dependecy using AutoFac.

Below is the classes I am using.

```
public abstract class DomainObject<IdT> : IDomainObject<IdT> 
{
    public virtual IdT Id { get; set; }
}


public class Course : DomainObject<long>
{
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}

public class  Teacher : DomainObject<long>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map CourseDTO to Course ,  the TeacherID has to be mapped to Teacher object

```
public class  CourseDTO
{
    public  long  Id{ get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public long TeacherID { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the entity converter.

```
 public class EntityConverter<T,IdT> : ITypeConverter<IdT, T>
 {
    private readonly IGenericRepository<T, IdT> _repository;
    public EntityConverter(IGenericRepository<T, IdT> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public T Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _repository.GetById((IdT)context.SourceValue);
    }
 }
```

How can I define the mapping and inject the dependency using AutoFac.

Comment: Which type would you like to inject ? and where ?

Comment: @Cyril Durand - Please refer the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525120/can-automapper-map-a-foreign-key-to-an-object-using-a-repository .I am trying to achieve this using autofac instated of Castle Windsor

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what you are having trouble with.  If you're just trying to map the TeacherId in your DTO, then there is no work to do at all:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Course, CourseDTO>();
```

TeacherId will be mapped automatically from Teacher.Id.

If you're wanting to map a TeacherDTO by looking it up from the repository, then you can use the approach in the linked question.  Registration will be very similar to the Windsor approach, and setting up the container for resolution is almost identical too:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var container = builder.Build();
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(container.Resolve));
```

If you're trying to do more complicated things than this, then you'll need to post the actual DTOs you're trying to map to.